# Is there a base version of jQuery which has no XSS vulnerability?

Tags: xss, vulnerability, jquery

I am working on an enterprise project and we have a upcoming new release. The security team runs a security scan, in that vulnerability report there is one point that I am struggling with. The project uses jQuery 1.4.x and it causes a XSS vulnerability, namely [this one](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2432). I need to upgrade jQuery but the latest version will cause a lot of problems. My question is there least version of jQuery that is striped from the XSS vulnerability?

Comment: I recently wrote [a blog post](https://www.sjoerdlangkemper.nl/2017/09/27/some-libraries-evaluate-remote-javascript/) about this. I think your best option is to  disable the execution of JavaScript responses using `$.ajaxSetup({contents: {script: false}})`.

Comment: You can also sanitize the input and/or patch the vulnerable JQuery yourself

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get away from the reported issues, (which will show up via projects like [retire JS](https://retirejs.github.io/retire.js/)), you'll need to use a JQuery version in the 3.x line. At least one of the commonly referenced issues ([this one](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2432)) required breaking changes and as such was never fixed in the 1.X stream.

The current latest version is 3.2.1 and I'm not aware of it having any disclosed XSS issues.

Comment: Can the JQuery version 2.x line be suffice for this situation because I need to avoid from major update?

Comment: I'm afraid reading down that issue the last comment from the developers appears to be "Yes, this was a breaking change so we couldn't include it in 2.x now that we follow semver.

Also, we no longer maintain jQuery 1.x/2.x, only the latest version, currently 3.x." so it sounds like you'd need 3.x

Comment: Thank you! It seems like it has to be updated to the current version to make it work.